# How to manage memory alignments and generic pointer arithmetics in a portable way in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I have to implement an optimized version of malloc/realloc/free (tailored for my particular application). At the moment the code runs on a particular platform, but I would like to write it in a portable way, if possible (the platform may change in the future), or at least I would like to concentrate the possible platform differences in a single point (probably a .h). I am aware of some of the problems:

- differences in memory alignment
- differences in smallest memory blocks size suitable for "generic" allocation
- differences in pointer size

(I'll ignore the differences in the basic system services for memory allocation here, since on some embedded systems they may be unavailable at all. Let's imagine that we work on a big preallocated memory block to be used as "heap").

The question(s):

- Are there standard macros or functions in C for this kind of purpose?
- What other issues may I face in this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alignment features are only handled in the new C standard, C11. It has keywords `_Alignof`, `_Alignas` and a function `aligned_alloc`. Theses features are not very difficult to emulate with most modern compilers (as indicated in other answers), so I'd suggest you write yourself small macros or wrappers that you'd use depending on `__STDC_VERSION__`.

Comment: Thank you! Using _Alignof & friends (and implementing them in a platform-specific file if the SDK doesn't do it) is the more clean way.

Comment: The OP asks for portable code and your answer is C11? As far as I know, there isn't any compiler support for this anywhere yet. In fact, plenty of compilers don't even support C99. Using C11-specific features is probably a certain way to make the code non-portable for the next 5-10 years or so.

Comment: @Lundin, I don't say that he should use it, I say he should emulate it, these are the interfaces to go with. Support for C11 will come much quicker than for C99. It basically adds features that are already there (like this one, alignment), or makes others optional (like VLA, threads or atomics).

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: Correct, that's the way I was imaginig.

Comment: @Lundin: I have just discussed more deeply this issue with Shane McLaughlin, see below. Thanks to all you!

Answer (score 3):

The classic way to ensure that you maintain alignment suitable for all the basic types is to define a union:

```
union alloc_align {
    void *dummy1;
    long long dummy2;
    long double dummy3;
};
```

...then ensure that the addresses you hand out are always offset by a multiple of `sizeof (union alloc_align)` from the aligned addresses you recieve from the system memory allocator.

I believe a method similar to this is described in K&R.

Comment: Old-fashioned, but it may work. I'd add "intptr_t" and a pointer to function. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

aligned memory differs from compiler to compiler unfortunately (this is one issue), on MSVC, you have `aligned_malloc`, you also have POSIX [`memalign`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memalign) for Linux, and then there is also `_mm_alloc`  which works under ICC, MSVC and GCC, IIRC, which should be the most portable.

The second issue is memory wastage from aligning it, it wouldn't be major, but on embedded systems, its something to take note of.

if you are stack allocating things that require alignment (like SIMD types), you also want to look into `__attribute__((__aligned__(x)))` and `__declspec(align(x))`.

in terms of portability of pointer arithmetic, you can use the types from `stdint.h`/`pstdint.h` to do it, but the standards may say something about UB when casting between `uintptr_t` and a pointer (unfortunately standards aren't my strong point :().

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately standards seems to be very weak in this kind of issues :( ...

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you only provide the total size of the memory block to `malloc()` and friends, without any information about the object granularity. If you view an allocation as an array of objects, then you have a size that is the sizeof of the basic object, and a number n that is the number of objects in the array, e.g.:

```
p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * n);
```

If you have only the total size, then you don't know if s=4 and n=10, or if s=2 and n=20, or s=1 and n=40, because all multiply to the total size of 40 bytes.

So the basic question is, do you want a direct substitute for the original functions, e.g. when you have thrown native calls all over your code base, or do you have a centralized and DRY modularity with wrapper functions. There you could use functions that provide s and n.

```
void *my_malloc (size_t s, size_t n)
```

Most of the time it should be a safe bet when the returned absolute memory address is a multiple of s to guarantee correct alignment.

Alternatively, when porting your implementation, you simply look at the alignment that the native `malloc()` uses for the target platform (e.g. multiples of 16), and use this for your own implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, for many reasons, I need a "plain" malloc replacement. You are perfectly right: if I could make some assumption about the objects to allocate, my job would be simpler. But there is too much code to touch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at #pragma pack, this may help you as it allows you to define structure packing and is implemented on most compilers.

Comment: But... The pointers produced by malloc must preserve the alignment and packing constraints characteristic of the platform. So I should meet instead of modify them. "#pragma pack" may help me in developing the core allocation engine instead, and here you are right. But my question was more about how to know (and fulfill) the system constraints in a way as standard as possible. Bye!

Comment: `#pragma pack` is definitely totally NONportable.

Comment: @JanHudec: it works on MSVC, GCC, ICC, WATCOM and a few others, seems pretty portable to me (it might not be *standardized* however).

Comment: @Giuseppe Guerrini: Standard is not the same as portable.  Your accepted answer conforms to emerging standards, but these standards have not yet been implemented for many platforms and hence are not particularly portable.  Look at compiler support for Windows CE or mobile for example. For maximum portability you want code that has been vanilla code for many years, not the latest and greatest new editions to the language.

Comment: Generally speaking, you are right. My goal is to produce a "well written" core engine in which all the "best practices" are applied (_Alignof ...), and a "system dependent" layer as small as possible where the leaks of each SDK are fixed. Ideally, in a (probably far :-( ) future, all the SDK should implement the "best pactices" and the "system dependent" part should disappear. That's my hope. Am I a dreamer? :D

Comment: PS: +1 for your comment! (and sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Not a dreamer at all, but once you start hitting a number of different platforms with different compilers, those #ifdef statements can be difficult to avoid.  As you say packaging them off into a separate layer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

C says `malloc` returns a pointer to memory aligned for any purpose. There is no portable way in C to achieve that with C features. This has the consequence that `malloc` is a function that if written in C cannot be written in a portable way.

> (C99, 7.20.3p1) "The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated)."

Comment: To make it portable: What about casting the pointer to (char*) and adding the correct offset. That would be defined.